# How can I change Niginx php.ini configuration?

Tags: php, macos, nginx, bitnami

I have installed Bitnami Nginx stack on my local OSX system. I not able to change [phpinfo.php] file. How can I change php.ini file. *allow_url_include   Off Off*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, this setting is set to Off. Anyway, you can edit this file. It is located at:

> /installdir/php/etc/php.ini

Later, you should restart the services for changes to take effect. You can do it by executing this command.

> /installdir/ctlscript.sh restart

Answer (score 0):

Try below link it might be help

http://butlerccwebdev.net/support/testingserver/configure-php.html

Comment: This not for Niginx Stack you mention apache.